# Proper way to pass a hard-coded value from route to controller (Laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a `PagesController` with one action: `view`. 
This action accepts a `page` argument.

What I want to achieve:

Have a routes `example.com/about` and `example.com/foobar`. 
When one of this routes is triggered, pass a value predefined in routes file to `PagesController@view`.

In my routes file:

```
Route::get('about', function () {
    return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\PagesController')->view('about');
})->name('aboutPage');

Route::get('foobar', function () {
    return App::make('App\Http\Controllers\PagesController')->view('foobar');
})->name('foobarPage');
```

It works as expected, but I want to know is there a better and more proper way to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass your pages as route parameter:

```php
Route::get('{page}', 'PagesController@view');

//controller
public function view($page)
{
    //$page is your value passed by route;
    return view($page);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case every request to `domain.com/something` will trigger  `PagesController@view`. Maybe there is a way to constrain possible values of `{page}`?

Comment: You can check if requested view exists like this: `if(view()->exists($page)) { return view($page)} else {abort(404)}`. Another way is adding regexp to your route `Route::get('{page}', 'PagesController@view')->where('page', '(about)|(foobar)');` but in this case you should manually enumarate all existing pages

Answer (score 2):

So you just want an argument to your action. You can use optional parameters if that argument can be empty. You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-optional-parameters).

```php
Route::get('{argument?}', 'PagesController@view')->name('page');
```

And in your `PagesController`:

```php
public function view($argument = 'default') {
    // Your logic
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is what you want based on what you are doing.

If you really wanted a hardcoded value you can use the 'actions' array part of the route if you wanted.

```
Route::get('something', ['uses' => 'Controller@page', 'page' => 'something']);

public function page(Request $request)
{
    $page = $request->route()->getAction()['page'];
    ...
}
```

[asklagbox - blog - random tips and tricks](http://asklagbox.com/blog/random-tips-tricks#routing-hardcoded-values)

Comment: You can even pass 'page' like `getAction('page')`. See https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getAction

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the names of the routes like in your example

```
->name('foobarPage');
```

you can use something like this

```
Route::get('{page_name}','PagesController@view')->where('page_name', '(about)|(foobar)');
```

This will accept only the values passed in the regular expression for the page_name parameter. Other routes will throw a 404 error. I should mention that this technique seems to be valid for applications with one level of url nesting only and **should NOT be used as a pattern.**

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see above if all you are doing is showing the correct view I would go for

```
Route::get('{page}', function($page)
{
    if (view()->exists($page)) { 
        return view($page);
    } 
    return abort(404);
});
```

This prevents you even needing a method in your controller.